# How obtain the intercept of the PLS-Regression (sklearn)

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

The PLS regression using sklearn gives very poor prediction results. When I get the model I can not find the way to find the "intercept". Perhaps this affects the prediction of the model? The matrix of scores and loadings are fine. The arrangement of the coefficients also. In any case, how do I get the intercept using the attributes already obtained?

This code throws the coefficients of the variables.

```
from pandas import DataFrame
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression

X = DataFrame( {
        'x1': [0.0,1.0,2.0,2.0],
        'x2': [0.0,0.0,2.0,5.0],
        'x3': [1.0,0.0,2.0,4.0],
    }, columns = ['x1', 'x2', 'x3'] )
Y = DataFrame({
        'y': [ -0.2, 1.1, 5.9, 12.3 ],
    }, columns = ['y'] )

def regPLS1(X,Y):
    _COMPS_ = len(X.columns) # all latent variables
    model = PLSRegression(_COMPS_).fit( X, Y )
    return model.coef_
```

The result is:

```
regPLS1(X,Y)
>>> array([[ 0.84], [ 2.44], [-0.46]])
```

In addition to these coefficients, the value of the intercept is: 0.26. What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT*
The correct predict(evaluate) response is Y_hat (exactly the same the observed Y):

```
Y_hat = [-0.2  1.1  5.9 12.3]
```

Comment: What about predicting `[0, 0, 0, 0]` ?

Comment: I have edited my answer. The predicted value (using 3 VL) is exactly equal to the observed value.

Comment: Using model.predict(X) obtain:

Comment: You have to predict your data. You don't in the snippet you show us

Comment: Using model.predict(X) obtain: array([[ 2.07322661], [ 3.21992642], [ 5.62383293], [ 8.18301403]])

Comment: What's your question I don't get it. Find the intercept ? Then I don't get the `the value of the intercept is: 0.26. What am I doing wrong?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To calculate the intercept use the following:

```
plsModel = PLSRegression(_COMPS_).fit( X, Y )

y_intercept = plsModel.y_mean_ - numpy.dot(plsModel.x_mean_ , plsModel.coef_)
```

I got the formula directly from the R "pls" package:

```
 BInt[1,,i] <- object$Ymeans - object$Xmeans %*% B[,,i]
```

I tested the results and calculated the same intercepts in R 'pls' and scikit-learn.

Comment: Yep, now generating the complete model output the predicted values correctly.
`plsModel.predict(X)` predicts wrong, or do not know exactly predicts.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Based of my reading of the implementation of [`_PLS`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b7e370244795c291fc8ac10686ce5867adde988e/sklearn/cross_decomposition/pls_.py#L124) the formula is `Y = XB + Err` where `model.coef_` is the estimate of `B`. If you look at the [`predict`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b7e370244795c291fc8ac10686ce5867adde988e/sklearn/cross_decomposition/pls_.py#L440) method it looks like it uses the fitted parameter `y_mean_` as the `Err` so I believe that's what you want. Use `model.y_mean_` instead of `model.coef_`. Hope this helps!

Comment: That's true, but I mean the constants of the predictive model. Once all latent variables were obtained. I would like to know what the model is in terms of constants and predictors. Using the same data in R I get both the coefficients and an intercept. And clearly the prediction is much better. I've done it in R and by hand using the Geladi & Kowalski algorithm ["Partial least-squares regression: a tutorial", Analytica Chimica Acta, 185 (1986)].

Comment: To clarify. `model.coef_` corresponds to `B` in the model. `model.y_mean_` corresponds to `Err` (the intercept) in them model. If you're getting much worse results it might be that you found a bug in the implementation. It  might be worth digging through the R implementation and identifying if they using `y_mean_` as the intercept or not. If not you might want to consider submitting an issue or bugfix to sklearn.

Comment: ohhh ... yep! I am using two packages ( "pls" & "plsdepot") for pls-regression and the prediction is good. Clearly the predict values [[ 2.07322661], [ 3.21992642], [ 5.62383293], [ 8.18301403]] are far from the observed values ...How do I report a bugfix on sklearn?