# Why the result is different between Matlab and scikit-learn when using PLS regression?

Tags: python, matlab, scikit-learn, regression

I use PLSRegression.predict form sklearn.cross_decomposition and plsregress  from MATLAB(2014a) and the result is a little different. I'm sure I used the same components and data. Matlab always performs better than scikit-learn.

Python:

```
from sklearn.cross_decomposition import PLSRegression
pls = PLSRegression(n_components=8)
pls.fit(X_train, Y_train)
Y_pred = pls.predict(X_train)
```

Matlab:

```
[XL,YL,XS,YS,BETA,PCTVAR,MSE]=plsregress(X_train , Y_train ,8);
Yfit = [ones(size(X_train,1),1) X_train]*BETA;
```

Comment: Please also have a look at other params in PLS like iterations, scaling, tolerance value etc.

Comment: Thank you. I tried but that didn't work.@VivekKumar

Answer (score 1):

I believe that scikit-learn uses the NIPALS algorithm for PLS, whereas MATLAB uses the SIMPLS algorithm. They are likely to give slightly differing results.

See the documentation page for [`plsregress`](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/stats/plsregress.html) in MATLAB, with a reference to the algorithm at the bottom. I don't have a convenient link for NIPALS, but it's an algorithm by Svante Wold, and fairly widely described on the internet.

Comment: You are right. But I doubt that scikit-learn's pls is wrong. Not only one person thinks at least pls.predict is wrong.[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41188410/how-obtain-the-intercept-of-the-pls-regression-sklearn/42238692#42238692)

Comment: I'm not saying scikit-learn is wrong, or that MATLAB is wrong. They just use different algorithms, so it's no surprise if they give slightly different results.